# Question on Dask -- how to incorporate to a script using pandas dataframe (groupby/apply)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I am trying to change my code a bit to incorporate Dask as I have too much data for pandas to handle.

This is what I have with pandas data frame:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['a', 'b', 'c'],  right_on=['a', 'b', 'c'],  suffixes=('', '_DROP'))
df = df.filter(regex='^(?!.*_DROP)').sort_values(['a', 'b']) 

df['x'] = df.groupby('a').apply( lambda group: 1 * (group['b'] == group['b'].min())).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

df['z'] = df.groupby('a')['m'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
```

Using task data frame, I have this so far:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['a', 'b', 'c'],  right_on=['a', 'b', 'c'],  suffixes=('', '_DROP'))

 keep_columns = list(filter(lambda v: match('^(?!.*_DROP)', v), df.columns))  

df = df[keep_columns]
```

But because of the sort, I cannot/do not know how to do the groupby+apply and keep the order. Maybe merging?

Another though is creation index with 'a'+'b', as if it were a multilevel index -- Dask doesn't support multilevel. But not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: You can do a hash repartition to ensure all keys of a certain value are in the same partition, followed by a within-partition sort, and finally within-partition groupby operations. Look into `ddf.shuffle` and `ddf.map_partitions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code with inline comments:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(300, 4)), columns=list("mabc"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(500, 5)), columns=list("abcde"))
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=3)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=4)

# obviate the need to drop columns after the merge
ddf = ddf1.merge(ddf2[[c for c in ddf2.columns if c in ddf1.columns]] , how='inner', on=['a', 'b', 'c'])

# apply functions on groupby
def func(df):
    df = df.sort_values('b')
    df['x'] = (df['b']==df['b'].min())
    df['z'] = df['m'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
    return df

new_ddf = ddf.groupby('a').apply(func, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=ddf.columns.tolist()+['x','z'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit unclear about the compute() at the end. Would this be necessary? I have so much data that I am avoiding that -- I will eventually do ```to_csv()``` and save to disk (unless there is a better way for this) -- I am very new to Task.

Comment: Also, I don't believe your assignation of "z" works -- you are grouping and hence rearranging. When this is assigned as "z" column to ddf it won't be for the correct row.

Comment: re: `compute()`, yes, if you are saving to csv, this step is not necessary. re: `z`, it should work the same way as your `pandas` code, please check on a small sample.

Comment: OK, I see your point re `z`. Let me think about the fix for this.

Comment: the changed version should be the same as your pandas code

Comment: Could you explain why "meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=list("mabcxz"))" is necessary? I have a lot of columns (+100) with long names so trying to find something more automated then "mabcxz."

Comment: you can omit it, but you'll see a warning. The main point is you want to tell dask what columns to expect, if you know that they are the same columns as ddf, you can do `ddf.groupby('a').apply(func, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=ddf.columns.tolist()+['x','z'])).compute().reset_index(drop=True)` (so x and z are created, so they have to be added)

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. What about the reset_index, I noticed you are adding it after compute(), is there a reason for not doing it before it? -- In my case, so I can ```to_csv()``` with index_reset (also noticed Dask dataframe doesn't have the level flag)

Comment: Nope, no reason. The thing is that the indexed column is also in the partitions/groupby elements with apply, so you want to drop the duplicated value of that column.

Comment: by indexed column you mean 'a'? If I do ```ddf.groupby('a').apply(func, meta=pd.DataFrame(columns=ddf.columns.tolist()+['x','z'])).reset_index(drop=True).compute()``` I don't see 'a' twice?

Comment: Yes...try removing the reset index to see what happens

Comment: Thanks so much! This works. I was hoping to ask one more question out of curiosity, when I save to csv (i.e., ```ddf.to_csv('path')```), it takes super long because it is a lot of data ~ 20 GB. Do you have any recommendations on what to do about this? What to look into? I am open to exploring anything (that is free): database, format, etc -- not sure what could work best with Dask.

Comment: One recommendation is to use `to_parquet` (smaller file sizes, faster load time), however one thing to note is to try it on some samples (I usually use parquet, but sometimes there are problems with saving complex data types). There are lots of other useful info here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html